# 24/7 with Hibernate and multiple sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, mariadb

For a project I'm working on, I've a Hibernate-related question.
First an overview of the problem.

For a public transport system, we receive about 600 messages per minute, 24/7.
In the database is a table where all journeys for this current day are stored, with for all journeys all stops where that specific journey has to stop.

> So bus 1 drives journey 1, and stops at the stops 1, 2 and 3.

The information from the received messages should be added to the journey. So when an arrival-message arrives, look in the database for the corresponding journey, find the corresponding stop, update the arrival-time and update the row in the database.
And this 600 times per minute.

> So when bus 1 arrives at stop 1 at 10:00, it sends a messages with timestamp 10:00, 
>   In the database, for journey 1, 10:00 should be added to stop 1

Well, so far, so good. However, the journeys that are valid for this day need to be collected at some moment. This is a separate process, which looks in various tables for the required information, collects the data and stores it in the journey table.

> So, a process that creates rows in the table like this:
>       In the journey table:
>       [id, name]
>       1, 1
>
> In the stops table:
>       [id, name, journeyref]
>       1, 1, 1
>       2, 2, 1
>       3, 3, 1

We have a MariaDB database, in combination Hibernate 4.3.6.

Our current implementation:

When process A (the handle incoming messages process) is started, it opens a Hibernate session, and starts using it. It starts a transaction, retreives data from the database, updates rows and every x updates (in our case 100) it performs a commit, a flush and starts a new transaction.
When process B wants to start, it opens a Hibernate session, but then the trouble starts, and both sessions crash, or cease to work.
(By the way, there are many more processes working on the database, but as long as a different table is used, no problems arise.)

Does any of you know how this could be solved?
Smaller Sessions?
Different implementation?
Other ideas?

Comment: 600 independent `INSERTs` (or `UPDATEs`) per minute is not a performance problem.  6000 might be.  Can you elaborate on why you are worried?  (Multiple processes would not be an issue.)

Comment: It's not a performance issue. The problem is that two HIbernate Sessions working on the same table at the same time seem to hinder each other. Hmm, now I get a "org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: object already associated, but no entry was found" exception when adding new data to the table in process B, while process A is still working.

Comment: By doing 1 record per 1 transaction, and having only 10 transactions per second, the server should keep up.  By doing 100 records at a time has less impact on the system but increases the chance that two threads will collide with a deadlock.  You _imply_ that Hibernate has Transactions?